# Django error, local variable 'data11' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, django-views

tengo este error en el código. He visto muchas preguntas relacionadas con esto, pero ninguna me ha podido ayudar, este código es antiguo, antes me funcionaba bien, pero ahora al ejecutarlo me muestra este problema y no he podido resolverlo. Entiendo que la variable está siendo referenciada antes de la asignación. De nuevo, he visto errores de otras personas como este, pero ninguna respuesta me ha ayudado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la vista, donde se "ubica" el supuesto error, además, dejo más detalles sobre el código.

```
def home(request):
solicitudes =  solicitud.objects.order_by('-id')
solicitudes2 = productor_crear_solicitud.objects.order_by('-id')
subastas = productor_crear_solicitud.objects.order_by('-id')

boletas2 = boleta.objects.order_by('-id')
contexto = {'solicitudes':solicitudes}

boletas = boleta.objects.count()
total11 = 0
total12 = 0
year = datetime.now().year

#enero
for m in range(0,boletas):

    data11 = [  ]    
   
    if  boleta.objects.filter(fec_boleta__month=11):
        total11 = total11 +1

    else:
        total11 = 0

    data11.append((total11))
   
    data12 = [  ]    
   
    if  boleta.objects.filter(fec_boleta__day=12):
        total12 = total12 +1

    else:
        tota2 = 0

    data12.append((total12))

return  render(request, 'cuenta/home.html',{'solicitudes':solicitudes, 'subastas':subastas,'solicitudes2':solicitudes2, 'boletas':boletas2,'data11':data11, 'data12':data12 })
```

Además, te muestro la template, donde esta vista se llama. Casi al final se referencia la variable data 11

```
                   <div>
               
              
               <table class="table table-bordered">

                {% if user|has_role:'externo' or user|has_role:'interno'  %}
                <h3>Mis solicitudes de creación de lote pendientes</h3>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
            
                           
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Fruta espacio 1</th>
                            <th>Fruta espacio 2</th>
                            <th>Fruta espacio 3</th>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    
                    
                    {% if solicitudes  %}    
                    {% for p in solicitudes %}  
                        {% if p.usuario_fk.username == user.username %} 
                        {% if p.fk_estado_solicitud.desc_estado_solicitud  == "Pendiente"%} 
                            <tr>
                                <td> {{ p.id }} </td>
                                
                                <td>{{ p.fk_estado_solicitud  }} </td>
                            
                                <td>{{ p.nombre_fruta_espacio1  }} {{ p.kilos_fruta_espacio1 }} Kilos </td>
                                <td>{{ p.nombre_fruta_espacio2  }} {{ p.kilos_fruta_espacio2 }} Kilos </td>
                                <td>{{ p.nombre_fruta_espacio3  }} {{ p.kilos_fruta_espacio3 }} Kilos </td>
                                <td>
                                    {% load permission_tags %}
                                    {% if p.fk_estado_solicitud.desc_estado_solicitud  == "Pendiente" and p.usuario_fk.username == user.username  or  user|has_role:'moderador'  %}
                                    <a href="{%  url 'modificar_solicitud' p.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Modificar</a>
                                    {% endif %}

                                    <a href="#" onclick="eliminarSolicitud({{ p.id }})  " class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ">Eliminar</a>
                                    
                                    
                                    {% if  user|has_role:'moderador'  %}

                                    <a href="{%  url 'modificar_estado_solicitud' p.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Modificar Estado</a>
                                    {% endif %}

                                    {% if p.fk_estado_solicitud.desc_estado_solicitud  == "Aprobado" and user|has_role:'moderador'  %}
                                    <a href="{%  url 'productor_crear_solicitudes' p.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Crear lote</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}     
                    {% else %}
                    <h3>No hay registros</h3>
                    {% endif %}
                    </tbody>
    
                </table> 
                {% endif %}


                {% if user|has_role:'productor'   %}

                <h3>Mis solicitudes de lote pendientes</h3>
              
                <table class="table table-bordered">

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th> id </th>
                            <th> Cliente </th>
                            <th> Estado </th>
                            <th> Fruta espacio 1  </th>
                            <th> Fruta espacio 2  </th>
                            <th> Fruta espacio 3  </th>
                            <th> Solicitud </th>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    {% if solicitudes2  %}    
    
                        {% for p in solicitudes2 %}  
                            
                            {% load permission_tags %}     
    
                            {% if p.fk_solicitud.usuario_fk.username == user.username or p.usuario_fk.username == user.username %}
                            {% if  p.fk_estado_productor_crear_solicitud.estado_venta  == "Pendiente"   %}
                                        
                            <tr>    
                                <td>{{ p.id }} </td>
                                <td>{{ p.fk_solicitud.usuario_fk  }}</td>
                                <td>{{ p.fk_estado_productor_crear_solicitud  }}</td>
                                <td>{{ p.fk_frutas_espacio1 }} a ${{p.fk_frutas_espacio1.fk_desc_fruta_espacio1.valor_producto }}   </td>
                                <td>{{ p.fk_frutas_espacio2  }} a ${{p.fk_frutas_espacio2.fk_desc_fruta_espacio2.valor_producto }} </td>
                                <td>{{ p.fk_frutas_espacio3  }} a ${{p.fk_frutas_espacio3.fk_desc_fruta_espacio3.valor_producto }}</td>
                                <td>{{ p.fk_solicitud }} </td>
                                <td>
                                    {% if  user|has_role:'productor' and p.usuario_fk.username  == user.username  %}
                                    <a href="#" onclick="eliminar({{ p.id }})  " class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ">Eliminar</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if  p.fk_estado_productor_crear_solicitud.estado_venta  == "Pendiente"   %}
                                        {% if  user|has_role:'externo' or user|has_role:'interno'   %}
                                        <a href="{%  url 'aprobar_solicitud_cliente_productor' p.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Aprobarr</a>
                                        <a href="{%  url 'rechazar_solicitud_cliente_productor' p.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Rechazar</a>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if p.fk_solicitud.usuario_fk.username  == user.username and  p.fk_estado_productor_crear_solicitud.estado_venta  == "Aprobado"  %}
                                    <a href="#" onclick="eliminar({{ p.id }})  " class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ">Eliminar</a>
                                    <a href="{%  url 'iniciar_subasta_participar' p.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Crear subasta</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if   p.fk_estado_productor_crear_solicitud.estado_venta  == "Subasta en curso"  %}
                                    <a href="{%  url 'listar_subasta' p.id p.fk_solicitud.usuario_fk p.fk_solicitud %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Ver subasta</a>
                                    {% endif %} 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}     
                    {% else %}
                    <h3>No hay registros</h3>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    </tbody>
                {% if user|has_role:'transportista'   %}
                <h3>Productos entregados</h3>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                {% if  p.fk_venta.fk_estado_venta.estado_venta != 'Productos entregados'%}
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Cliente </th>
                            <th>Id venta</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Transportista </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                      
                    {% for p in boletas %}   
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            {% if  p.fk_venta.fk_estado_venta.estado_venta == 'Productos entregados'%}
                            {% if p.fk_venta.fk_subasta.fk_transportistaa_usuario == user   %}
                            <td>{{ p.id  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ p.fec_boleta  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ p.usuario_fk  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ p.fk_venta  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ p.fk_venta.fk_estado_venta  }}</td>
                            <td>{{ p.fk_venta.fk_subasta.fk_transportistaa_usuario }}</td>
                            {% endif %}    
                            {% endif %}  
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %} 
                    
                    
                {% else %}
                <h3>No hay registros</h3>
                {% endif %}



                    </tbody>
                </table>     
                {% endif %}  
            </table>

            </div>
            {% if user|has_role:'moderador'   or  user|has_role:'consultor'  %}
              
                
                <form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div id="container"></div>
                    <p class="highcharts-description">
                    </p>

                </div>
                <script >
                    Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Reporte de ventas del año'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: [
                                'Enero',
                                'Febrero',
                                'Marzo',
                                'Abril',
                                'Mayo',
                                'Junio',
                                'Julio',
                                'Agosto',
                                'Septiembre',
                                'Octubre',
                                'Noviembre',
                                'Diciembre'
                            ],
                            crosshair: true
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Cantidad de ventas'
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                            shared: true,
                            useHTML: true
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                pointPadding: 0.2,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Venta ',
                            showInLegend: false,
                            colorByPoint: true,
                            data:  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ,{{data11}} ]
                        }];
                    });
                </script>

                
            {% endif %}  
          
        </div>
```

Agradezco por tu ayuda

Comment: Hola estimado @ptr_022 este sitio es en español por ende no es necesario colocar la traduccion al ingles. En todo caso puedes publicar tu respuesta en el sitio en ingles de stackoverflow. Te exorto a que le des [edit] a tu pregunta y asi reduzcas un poco el texto! y ayudas a la legibilidad

Comment: la pregunta esta realizada en ingles

Comment: Hola, corregido;)

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice exactamente en que linea se esta generando

```
Local variable referenced before assignment in Python - Linea 72
```

Por ende al revisar el repositorio de tu código encontré que data11 ni data12 están definido fuera del ciclo for y son variables locales dentro del ciclo pero no fuera de el.
Al hacer return este no las encuentra en su ambito local (la función) ni global.

```
@login_required 
def home(request):
    solicitudes =  solicitud.objects.order_by('-id')
    solicitudes2 = productor_crear_solicitud.objects.order_by('-id')
    subastas = productor_crear_solicitud.objects.order_by('-id')
    
    boletas2 = boleta.objects.order_by('-id')
    contexto = {'solicitudes':solicitudes}

    boletas = boleta.objects.count()
    total11 = 0
    total12 = 0
    year = datetime.now().year

    data11 = []  # has referencia a ellas fuera del ciclo
    data12 = [] # ha referencia a  ellas fueras del ciclo

    #enero
    for m in range(0,boletas):   
       
        if  boleta.objects.filter(fec_boleta__month=11):
            total11 = total11 +1
        else:
            total11 = 0
    
        data11.append((total11))     
       
        if  boleta.objects.filter(fec_boleta__day=12):
            total12 = total12 +1

        else:
            tota2 = 0
    
        data12.append((total12))

    return  render(request, 'cuenta/home.html',{'solicitudes':solicitudes, 'subastas':subastas,'solicitudes2':solicitudes2, 'boletas':boletas2,'data11':data11,
```

Espero sea de ayuda

Comment: Excelente, si me sirvio totalmente. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!!

Comment: Agradable saber que se resolvió el error. Si esta respuesta te ayudo te exorto a que la marques como aceptada